# man pages don't line wrap correctly

Tags: bash, shell, man

Sometimes running `man` outputs badly line-wrapped text. If I run `man`, quit, then resize the terminal window and run `man` again, it formats it according to the new window width. But if I run `man`, resize the window (the text gets messy), quit, and then run man again, it still formats it badly like before.

But sometimes it doesn't happen even if I resize the window while `man` is running, and sometimes it happens even after I make a new, resized terminal **before running** `man` for the first time in that window.

How can this be fixed? I have tried the `man -c` option and R, r, ⌃R and ⌃L to “repaint” the screen while viewing the manpage (my `man` uses `less`).

I don't have MANWIDTH set. I'm using iTerm2.

Comment: Can I bump this question? http://i.imgur.com/plUSw.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a bad interaction between cat pages (the cache of already-formatted man pages) and the fact that `man` uses the current width of the terminal at time-of-formatting.  In the output of `man man` (the man page for the man command), I see:

```
No cat pages are saved when the required cat directory does not exist.
No cat pages are saved when they are formatted for a line length different
from 80.  No cat pages are saved when man.conf contains the line NOCACHE.
```

That may help.